# How to test for deleting an association in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have the following factory:

```
factory :store do
  room
  factory :store_with_items do
    ignore do
      items_count 4
    end

    after(:create) do |store, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:equippable_item, evaluator.items_count, store: store)
    end
  end
end
```

Next, I create an object:

```
@store = FactoryGirl.create :store_with_items
```

My problem is that when I "delete" one of the store's items, the store still shows that it has 4 items.

```
@store.items[0].store_id = nil
@store.save!
puts @store.items.size
```

The puts is 4.  How do I properly delete an item?  Isn't this how you would do it in rails?

Comment: What does the log say for SQL when you run `#save!`?

Comment: Good questions.  Looks like just this: (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1

Comment: There's no `update` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I used to prefer this approach, but now I avoid it; its easier and more flexible to let factories be simple and populate has_many associations at runtime.

### Try this

Factory for store (same):

```
factory :store do
  room
end
```

Factory for items:

```
factory :item do
  store # will use the store factory
end
```

Then in my test I would populate what is appropriate for the case at hand:

```
@store = FactoryGirl.create :store
@item1 = FactoryGirl.create :item, store: @store
@item2 = FactoryGirl.create :equippable_item_or_whatever_factory_i_use, store: @store
```

### To explain

By passing in the store instance explicitly, the association will be setup for you. This is because when you pass something explicitly in `FactoryGirl.create` or `FactoryGirl.build` it overrides whatever is defined in the factory definition. It even works with nil. This way, you'll have real object instances that give you all the real functionality.

### To test destroy

I think the code in your example is not good; it breaks the association between store and item, but doesn't actually remove the item record so you're leaving behind an orphan record. I would do this instead:

```
@store.items[0].destroy
puts @store.items.size
```

### Bonus

You probably also want to setup your child associations to be destroyed when the parent is destroyed if its not already. This would mean when you say `@store.destroy` all the items belonging to it will also be destroyed (removed from the db.)

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  .....
end
```

Comment: I like this approach of managing associations much better and plan to use it going forward.  I'm still left with the problem of testing "destroy".  I do not want to destroy an item, I just want to transfer it from being associated from one model to a different model.  Think of it like an item in a game.  The item originally belongs to the store, but after the user purchases the item from the store, the store loses it from its' inventory and the user gains it in his inventory.  So I do not want to destroy the item, just transfer it.